# Transform React Native export file in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

How can I translate this .js file into a Typescript one?

```
import * as Colors from './colors';
import * as Spacing from './spacing';
import * as Typography from './typography';
import * as Mixins from './mixins';

export { Typography, Spacing, Colors, Mixins };
```

Thank you

Edit 1:
I'm trying to fix the folowing error:

Cannot find module '_styles' or its corresponding type declarations.

When trying to import a file in another file

```
import {Colors,Typography,Mixins} from '_styles';
```

It works, but shows the above warning.
I have a setup that allow my to import the file without the complete path that works well but with typescript, it shows a warning.

Edit 2:

I have the following setup in .babelrc

```
    {
  "plugins": [
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "cwd": "babelrc",
        "root": ["./src"],
        "extensions": [".js", ".ios.js", ".android.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".json"],
        "alias": {
          "_assets": "./src/assets",
          "_components": "./src/components",
          "_atoms": "./src/components/atoms",
          "_molecules": "./src/components/molecules",
          "_organisms": "./src/components/organisms",
          "_navigations": "./src/navigations",
          "_scenes": "./src/scenes",
          "_services": "./src/services",
          "_styles": "./src/styles",
          "_utils": "./src/utils",
          "_i18n": "./src/i18n"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From TS 3.8 the new syntax is introduces [export * as ns from '...'](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#export--as-ns-syntax)

How about use this?

```js
export * as Colors from './colors';
export * as Spacing from './spacing';
export * as Typography from './typography';
export * as Mixins from './mixins';
```

Comment: This throws an error: Unexpected export specifier type ...

Comment: I think you can just use your code in typescript is there any error with that?

Comment: I get an error in another file: Cannot find module '_styles' or its corresponding type declarations. let me update my question.

Comment: is `_styles` javascript file? Then turn on `allowJS` as `"allowJS": true` option in `tsconfig.json`

Comment: _styles refers to this file, in which I export all my other files from.